# How can implement mulitiple filters?

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Model

qs = Model.objects.filter(Q(field_1=value1)&Q(field_2=value2))
```

I know how to form query_set but how can I link it with the front-end dynamically, so that I can know which filter option does the user chose?

Comment: Could you add some additional information how / in what form the data is coming from your front-end? This could help in giving you a more detailed answer

Comment: well, I made a model that has details of the property. And now I want to add filters so that the user can get desired property. One more there are many filters like Super Area Max, Super Area Min, Carpet Area,etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pipe symbol to query multiple fields

```
query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            qs = Model.objects.filter(
                Q(field_1__icontains=query)|
                Q(field_2__icontains=query)
            )
        return qs
```

Comment: Chaining is the correct approach, but I beleive your query is an OR query and the OP wants an AND query. For an AND query you should use "&" instead of "|"

Comment: @Chris, sorry, haven't done AND query yet, this way can query from any required fields

Comment: Yeah, I can do that but the problem is there are too many filters and some times I have to handle many filters simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Based on bemons reply you could do the following.

Let's assume you have a dict where the key is the field - name and the value is the value to filter for, e.g.:

```
filter_dict = {
    'field_1': 'value1'
    'field_2': 'value2'
}
```

Then you could build a chain of filters like so:

```
q = Q()

for k, v in filter_dict.items():
    x = {k, v}
    q = q & Q(**x)

qs = Model.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: Chris, although I faced some issues while doing the way you suggested but I got an idea that how things should work.
Thanks man